# Python Gtk3 - Scroll TextView inside of ScrolledWindow by mouse and courser position

Tags: python, gtk

I have some text in a Gtk.TextView

When I select the text with my mouse or navigate the cursor beyond the bottom edge I cannot se my selection because it does not scroll.

So I think I need to get cursor position and set treeview to this position.
And mouse position while button is clicked and move treeview to this position.

- https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeView
- https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/ScrolledWindow
- https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class ScrolledWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_default_size(200, 200)
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

        self.scrolledwindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()

        self.add(self.scrolledwindow)

        box = Gtk.Box()
        self.scrolledwindow.add(box)

        textview = Gtk.TextView()
        box.pack_start(textview, True, True, 10)
        
        textview.connect("move-cursor", self.move_cursor_event) # arrow keys
        textview.connect("key-press-event", self.key_press_event) # keyboard input
        textview.connect("button-press-event", self.button_press_event) # mouse click 
        
        textbuffer = textview.get_buffer()
        
        text = 50*"Hello World\n"
        
        textbuffer.set_text(text, len(text))
        
    def move_cursor_event(self, tree_view, step, count, extend_selection):
        print "move_cursor_event", step, count, extend_selection
        
    def key_press_event(self, widget, event):
        print "key_press_event", event
        
    def button_press_event(self, widget, event):
        print "button_press_event", event.x, event.y
        position = self.scrolledwindow.get_vadjustment()
        position.set_value(350) 
        self.scrolledwindow.set_vadjustment(position)  #scroll to the middle of the scolled window
        

window = ScrolledWindow()
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

Thanks

#### edit1

here is a very basic solution I found for scrolling the window to the cursor position changed by arrow keys:

```py
def move_cursor_event(self, tree_view, step, count, extend_selection):
    rect = tree_view.get_cursor_locations()
    self.scroll_y(rect.strong.y)

def scroll_y(self, ypos):
    vadj = self.scrolled_window.get_vadjustment()
    vadj.set_value(ypos-80) 
    self.scrolled_window.set_vadjustment(vadj)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `textview` is put inside a box, which is then put inside `self.scrolledwindow`. When the `TextView` is inside a `Box`, it prevents the `ScrolledWindow` from recognizing that the `TextView` needs to be scrolled. Placing the `TextView` directly in the `ScrolledWindow` should fix this problem. Here is what the code should look like:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class ScrolledWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_default_size(200, 200)
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

        self.scrolledwindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()

        self.add(self.scrolledwindow)

        textview = Gtk.TextView()
        self.scrolledwindow.add(textview)
        
        textbuffer = textview.get_buffer()
        
        text = 50*"Hello World\n"
        
        textbuffer.set_text(text, len(text))  #scroll to the middle of the scolled window
        
window = ScrolledWindow()
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```